# Использование сокетов в C++

Tags: c++, сокет

Я только начинающий программист в C++. Есть знания PHP.
В качестве среды выбрал code::blocks (ну во первых мне кажется она удобнее визуала, во вторых поддержка кроссплатформенности на высшем уровне что является основным поводом выбора code::blocks). **В качестве компилятора использую gcc**.

И так вопрос: как пользоваться сокетами? Конкретно нужны примеры и клиентского и серверного (слушающего) сокета. В интернете сколько примеров не находил, ни один не работает либо работает с использованием .NET, что мне совершенно не нужно.

Answer (score 5):

Windows:

[Крис Касперски. Самоучитель игры на winsock](http://web.archive.org/web/20140211050627/http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf)

Хорошая статейка. Я по ней писал работу с сокетами. Пример там 100% рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Unix:

- [Beej's Guide to Network Programming: Using Internet Socket](http://web.archive.org/web/20171013080401/http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4.pdf)

Windows:

- [Running the Winsock Client and Server Code Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737889(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Complete Winsock Client Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737591%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Complete Winsock Server Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737593%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Очень хорошая статья по программированию сетей Windows на русском](http://gamedev.ru/articles/?id=80201). Плюс МСДН по функциям в помощь.

Comment: > В качестве компилятра использую gcc.
Статья по WinSock тут навряд ли поможет :)