# Неблокирующий TCP сервер на С или С+

Tags: c++, c, клиент-сервер, tcp

Получил задание: "реализовать неблокирующий TCP сервер на С или С++". Как делать не понимаю от слова совсем. Прошу посоветовать книги по данной теме.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/192284/ - статья про boost.asio http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html - пример реализации на qt (отдельно смотрим реализацию многопоточного сервера) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13746/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-c - тут тоже некоторая инфа

Comment: Сервера разные бывают. Я бы на вашем месте начал с модификации простого эхо-сервера из стандартных [примеров boost::asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html). Там есть много мелочей, из-за которых с нуля создавать его не стоит, но модифицировать готовый не так уж сложно. С boost::asio главное помнить, что читать данные можно асинхронно без проблем, а вот отправлять можно либо синхронно, либо нужно вручную следить за тем, чтобы одновременно больше одного пакета не отправлялось - иначе могут перемешаться.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для Windows:

```
 unsigned long non_block = 1;
 ioctlsocket(sd, FIONBIO, &non_block);
```

Для Linux:

```
    int flags;
    if(-1 == (flags = fcntl(sd, F_GETFL)))
        flags = 0;
    return fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Для Unix-based ОС:

```
int set_nonblock(int sd) {
    int flags;
#ifdef O_NONBLOCK
    if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(sd, F_GETFL, 0)))
        flags = 0;
    return fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);    
#else
    flags = 1;
    return ioctl(sd, FIONBIO, &flags);
#endif  // O_NONBLOCK
}
```

Про сокеты Беркли: [видео на YouTube](https://youtu.be/UKgvHcqF7GU?list=PLwwk4BHih4fhYu3nMqgMbp_SkYC5Kv684), мне кажется, Вам пригодится.

> Как делать не понимаю от слова совсем

Посмотрите иерархию классов в Java, это немного поможет с интерфейсами Ваших классов. Думаю, это может выглядеть как-то так:

Интерфейс:

```
class ISocket {
public:
    virtual ~ISocket() = default;

    // interface
    virtual void        open(...) = 0;
    virtual bool        isOpen() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void        close() = 0;

    virtual int         descriptor() const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool        bind(...) = 0;
    virtual bool        listen(...) = 0;
    virtual ISocket*    accept(...) = 0;
    virtual void        enableNonblockingMode() = 0;
    // и.т.д
};
```

Базовый класс:

```
class CSocket : public ISocket { /* тут общая часть */};
```

TCP/UDP/SCTP/т.п.

```
class CTCPSocket : public CSocket { /* спец. для TCP */};
```

Comment: А за что минус? Хотя бы объясните :)

Answer (score 2):

Стивенс, Феннер и Рудофф - "UNIX Разработка сетевых приложений"

Comment: Вот здесь минус - точно не обоснованный. Это своего рода RTFM для тех, кто занимается разработкой сетевого ПО.

Comment: @isnullxbh у вопроса и обоих ответов одновременно появилось по минусу. Думаю, автор этих минусов считает, что вопрос недостоин ответов.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы ещё рекомендовал:

"Разработка приложений типа клиент/сервер для Linux/POSIX"
Дуглас Э. Камер

Там глава 13 - это для Вас.